# How to get {x, y} position of dropped element on drop section instead absolute position in React Dnd

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag, react-dnd

I am trying to drag pointer to drop section but I am not able to get position {x, y} relative to drop section. Using React DnD 16.0.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how i handled basicly:

```
const [localCoords, setLocalCoords] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});

const handleMouseMove = event => {
    // ️ Get the mouse position relative to the element
    setLocalCoords({
        x: event.clientX - event.target.offsetLeft,
        y: event.clientY - event.target.offsetTop,
    });
};  

<Item    onMouseUp={handleMouseMove} >
</Item>
```